# How to hide/show a div id with jQuery when html option select is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html option select with two options:

```
<select name="subject" id="subject">
   <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

I also have a div element with id="human-genome".

```
<div id="human-genome"></div>
```

I want to hide this id by default and when option 1 is selected. I want to show this id when option 2 is selected.

Here is my Jquery:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#subject").change(function(){
      if($(this.val() == 'option1'){
          $('#human-genome').hide();
      } else {
          $('#human-genome').show();
      });
   
});
```

For some reason, the code isn't working. Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the code you developed. I edited the code as follows to make it understandable.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#subject").change(function(){
    console.log(this.value);
    
    if(this.value == 'option1')
    {
      $('#human-genome').hide();
    }
    else
    {
      $('#human-genome').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#human-genome{
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="subject" id="subject">
   <option value="option1">Hide</option>
   <option value="option2">Show</option>
</select>

<div id="human-genome">TEST</div>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! In this example, however, the div id="human-genome" shows by default. How do I make it hidden until "option2" is selected?

Comment: @steph It was something I noticed. I edited it as you requested.

Comment: Sorry, I think my question was misunderstood. I'm struggling with the following: making the div hidden by default until option 2 (show) is selected. Thank you!

Comment: @steph I updated my answer. I've assigned the class style `human-genome` to `display: none`. In this case, the `<div>` element with an id of `human-genome` is hidden by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try use $(this).val() instead of your code please.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#subject").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'option1'){
      $('#human-genome').hide();
    } else {
      $('#human-genome').show();
    }});});
```